# two divs next to each other. JQUERY

Tags: jquery, html

I have a container that contains my content, and I am using  sideBar for my links. By default sidebar  puts it on the side of the page. So I edited the css to move it next to the div called container. But if people use different resolutions it throws it off.

first div is sidebar and the second is container. i tryed

```
<script>
$("sideBar").position({
 my: "center",
 at: "left bottom",
 of: $("container"),
})
</script>
```

and nothing happened

```
   <script>
$j("sideBar").position({
 my: "center",
 at: "left bottom",
 of: "#container",
})
</script>
```

```
<div id="sideBar">

    <a href="#" id="sideBarTab"><img src="sidebar/images/slide-button-active.gif" alt="sideBar" title="sideBar"></a>

    <div id="sideBarContents" style="opacity: 0.80;">
        <div id="sideBarContentsInner">
            <h2>side<span>bar</span></h2>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="goto('home');return false;">Link One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="goto('connect');return false;">Link Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="goto('contact');return false;">Link Three</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link Four</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link Five</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

```
<div id="container">
        <div style="height: 548px;" id="door"  onclick="openclose()">
    </div>
        <div id="nav" style="display: none;">
            <a href="#" id="social_" class="selected" onmouseover="hover(this)" onmouseout="out(this)" onclick="goto('social');return false;"><span id="social_hov" style=""></span></a>
            <a class="" href="#" id="connect_" onmouseover="hover(this)" onmouseout="out(this)" onclick="goto('connect');return false;"><span id="connect_hov" style="display: none;"></span></a>
            <a class="" href="#" id="contact_" onmouseover="hover(this)" onmouseout="out(this)" onclick="goto('contact');return false;"><span id="contact_hov" style="display: none;"></span></a>
            <a class="" href="http://wordpress.thechrismission.com/" target="_blank" id="portfolio_" onmouseover="hover(this)" onmouseout="out(this)"><span id="portfolio_hov" style="display: none;"></span></a>
        </div>

    <div id="social" style="display: none;">
        <div id="subheader">
                <div id="header" class="social"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
                <div id="list">
                    <a href="http://twitter.com/heychrishanna" target="_blank">twitter<span>twitter.com/heychrishanna</span><b class="icon twitter"></b></a>
                    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/ChristopherHanna" target="_blank">facebook<span>facebook.com/ChristopherHanna</span><b class="icon fb"></b></a>

                </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is just slightly off. It should be:

```
<script>
$("#sideBar").position({
 my: "center",
 at: "left bottom",
 of: "#container",
})
</script>
```

Comment: ("sideBar") should be ("#sideBar")

Answer (score 1):

Your script might run before the DOM is ready. You're also missing `#` characters before your element identifiers. Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#sideBar").position({
            my: "center",
            at: "left bottom",
            of: "#container"
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It should be: of: "#container"

Comment: @NEWprogrammer, that's hard to say. Everything in your container is initially hidden and there's a `548px`-tall `<div>` that pushes everything down. I tried to clean that up a little in [this fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/x2pDg/), you might want to experiment with it until you're satisfied with the result.

Answer (score 1):

If you divs have id="sideBar" or id="container" then you need to replace $("sideBar") with $("#sideBar") and $("container") with $("#container")

Of if you are using class=".. then it's $(".sideBar") .. etc

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to achieve this using just CSS. Look into [floats](http://www.elated.com/articles/css-floats/) for your positioning of the divs and be aware that if the combined widths of your divs (including margins and borders) exceed that of the parent container, the div will wrap to the next line.